# Moving files to another folder on Git Bash

Tags: git-bash

I am new on Git Bash and was trying to move a file named "text2.txt" from its folder named "test" to another folder named "new" using the following command: "mv text2.txt new" but it doesn't seem to work. All this being in the "test" directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your folder structure looks like this:

```
parentFolder
     |
     |_____ test
     |        |___ test2.txt
     |
     |_____ new
```

And you're in parentFolder, then try this:

```
mv test/test2.txt new/
```

But if you're in test directory, you can use the level-up operator `../`, something like:

```
mv test2.txt ../new/
```

to get one step back in order to access the "new" folder. Note that mv command has 2 parameters, the first being file's path (relative or absolute), and the second one - final folder's path (again, relative or absolute). Obviously, you have to make sure that both paths point to existing files / folders. You can find more information on this topic [here](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-move-files-using-linux-commands-or-file-managers/).

Comment: I used the first command and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: With pleasure :)